# Change XSD root namespace in BizTalk

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, biztalk

I want to change the schema namespace from

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

to

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
```

since it supports "override". But it shows error:

> The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be `<schema>` and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

Comment: Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve or something you're trying to work around?  Really, in practical terms, no one uses this so if there's something else going on, we can help you with that.

Comment: I want to override a complex type called in a schema. Using redefine I can only add another complexType. So I needed help in changing the complextype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure BizTalk does not support XML 1.1, the `xs:override` element, or schema versioning in this manner.  It would have trouble resolving which schema to use anyway, as both schemas would have the same `targetNamespace` and root nodes, and it needs those to be distinct to be able to perform schema resolution correctly.  You should just create a new schema with a new `targetNamespace`, e.g. `http://existing_target_ns/v2`.

Generally speaking, versioning in BizTalk is a bit tricky and can cause a lot of problems - bindings statically encode the version numbers of assemblies and must be updated, and the server runtime will choose the most recently deployed assembly regardless of version.  I've seen this cause many more problems than it could solve, and would suggest you read the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561436.aspx) on it.

Comment: I want to override a complex type called in a schema. Using redefine I can only add another complexType. So I needed help in changing the complextype.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your XML declaration from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
```

?

New features in XML 1.1 are described here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-guide2versioning/

Furthermore there are some browsers that seem still not have native support for the XML 1.1 version, which is discussed here: http://www.herongyang.com/XML/XML-1-1-Not-Supported-in-Web-Browser.html

Comment: I want to override a complex type called in a schema. Using redefine I can only add another complexType. So I needed help in changing the complextype and version 1.1 is not supported by Biztalk

Comment: @AvinashKumar You might want to edit your question to include the details of what you trying to accomplish with the redefine.